# Create new variables from mutiple values of a numeric variable in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression, dummy-variable

I am working on a dataset that has a variable sector with numeric values signifying different sectors for example 1 = finance, 2 = construction, 3 = utility etc. There are also several blank values for this variable sector.

I am trying to create a new variable sector_finance with values "yes" or "no" and using below code for the same.

data$sector_finance <- ifelse(data$sector == 1, "yes", "no")

But, when I am doing table(data$sector_finance), I am not getting blank values included in "no"

How can i get correct results with blank values included as well.

Comment: If data$sector is numeric with NA as the "blank values", you won't have a problem. Perhaps `data$sector` is a factor, with the a `' '` level?

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(
  sector = sample(c(1:3, NA_real_), 10, replace = TRUE)
)

data %>%  
  mutate(sector_finance = case_when(sector == 1 ~ "Yes",
                                    TRUE ~ "No"))

# A tibble: 10 x 2
   sector sector_finance
    <dbl> <chr>         
 1      3 No            
 2     NA No            
 3     NA No            
 4      3 No            
 5      3 No            
 6      2 No            
 7      3 No            
 8      3 No            
 9      1 Yes           
10     NA No
```